# Node creating file 1 level up from the current path

Tags: node.js, windows

I was using `path.resolve` but this command created a monster folder that can't be deleted called `lib..`

```js
path.resolve(__dirname + "../assets/pic/" + `${fileName}.png`)
```

#### Question 1

What is the propper usage to create a folder 1 level up from the current path?

#### Question 2

How to remove the `lib../assets/pic` folder? Deleting the entire project or using `git reset --hard`, `git stash` doesn't work because Windows 10 says the folder doesn't exist.

Comment: I had a similar issue with a path that was fine in Linux being difficult in Windows.  I used the `fs.rmdirSync` with the path hardcoded.  Basically, it was a short script to clean up the mess and worked.

Comment: You forgot a slash. You delete it like any other file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to Question 1:**

**tl;dr**

```
const fs = require('fs')
const folderName1DirUp = '../SomeFolder'
try {
  if (!fs.existsSync(folderName1DirUp)){
    fs.mkdirSync(folderName1DirUp)
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err)
}
```

**The back story:**

Two ways to reference the current folder in a *Node.js* script. You can use `./` or `__dirname`.  Note in addition to `./` you can also use `../` which points to the parent folder.

The difference between the two.

`__dirname` in a *Node* script will return the path of the folder where the **current *JavaScript* file resides**.

`./` will give you the **current working directory** (and `../` the parent). For `./` a call to `process.cwd().` returns the same thing.

Initially the **current working directory** is the path of the folder where you ran the `node` command, but during the execution of your script it can change by calling `process.chdir(...)`.

There is one place where `./` refers to the current file path which is in a `require(...)` call. There the `./`, for convenience, refers to the *JavaScript* file path which lets you import other modules based on the folder structure.

Thus the call to `fs.mkdirSync('../SomeFolder')` with the given folder name makes a folder one level up from the **current working directory**.

**Answer to Question 2:**

From a *PowerShell* prompt `Remove-Item './../Folder1UpToDelete' -Force`  The `./` is for the current folder. The `../` is for one folder up from the current. Finally the `Folder1UpToDelete` is the one folder up from the current that you want to delete. The `-Force` makes sure to delete all sub-folders/files under the folder you want deleted including hidden and/or read-only files.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first question, to create a path 1 level up, you can use [`path.join()`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths):

```js
path.join(__dirname, "../assets/pics", `${fileName}.png`);
```

For the second question, if deleting it through the explorer doesn't work, you can try:

- ```js
  fs.rmdirSync("E:/path/to/broken/folder..");
  ```
- Using Git Bash and running

  ```sh
  cd /c/path/to/broken/
  rmdir folder..
  ```